# How do I use GBP pound sterling symbol in Ruby on Rail's number to currency method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

I am quite new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails.

While following a Ruby guide to create a small food finding application, the author used the number to currency method from Ruby on Rails. The trouble is the default unit is `$` but I would like to change it to `£`.

When I did this in it gave me back the following error after I tried to run the code.

```
number_helper.rb:7 invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put the following in the first line of your file where you have `£`.

```
#coding: utf-8
```

By default, ruby can read one-byte characters, which are [US-ASCII characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aASCII_Code_Chart-Quick_ref_card.png). The `£` character does not fit within US-ASCII code, and the magic comment above let ruby read the file as UTF-8 code, which is becoming standard, and is capable of handeling multi-byte characters, including `£` (Added following the suggestion by the Tin Man).

**Edit**
With Ruby 2.0 to be published this month, the default encoding will be UTF-8, so you will not need to do this  anymore.

Comment: for completeness, you might want to explain why that is important. The extra information will make a much better answer.

Comment: great answer, i'd note that now, 2018, indeed utf8 is supported and one doesn't need that line, as you say.. but i'd also note that one gets a similar error to the OPs, if the file is encoded with 8859-1 and it has a symbol like £.  Notepad for example , and many text editors, default to ansi or 8859-1  and need to be changed to utf-8.  The hex for £ differs depending on whether 8859-1 or utf-8 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A3/index.htm  and one can see with the xxd command how it has been encoded. And the file command how the file is encoded.